# unable to create table on database in flask_sqlalchemy on repl.it

Tags: python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

**it seems that this problem only arises when i am using flask application factory method**

[here](https://repl.it/@gptsahaj28/foodTrack#main.py) is the link to repl, and

[here](https://repl.it/talk/ask/You-can-try-using-flask-sentry-to-track/46485) is the link to post i made asking fro help (Kindly read the comment section)

1. I have commented the *app.run()* part so that it won't start server

```py
#!main.py l:3
#if __name__ == '__main__':
#    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

2. After running the repl once on the console side i typed

```py
from app.main.models import *
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

now in theory these line of code should create database with table defined init such that if i do `Food.query.all` it should return (in theory) an empty list => `[]` but it returns an error `RuntimeError: No application found.`

**note** : Kindly fork the repl you don't need an account for that just click on the fork button beside run because it might show wired when many people run it together

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you've not commit the session & it's not the best practice to import function by *. You should specify specicfic module or Maybe you haven't insert any values in db so you are getting an empty list. I'm not sure about this.But your solution might be in between.